# A suitable constructor could not be found for type filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have this typefilter that was recently created and it is located in a separate project.

```
public class RolesFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RolesFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(RolesFilterAttributeImpl))
    {

    }

    public class RolesFilterAttributeImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient;
        private string Role;
        private string SecretKey;
        public RolesFilterAttributeImpl(string Role, string SecretKey, ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient)
        {
            this.validateRoleClient = validateRoleClient;
            this.Role = Role;
            this.SecretKey = SecretKey;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"] != null || context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
            {
                TokenViewModel tvm = new TokenViewModel
                {
                    Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Token"],
                    RefreshToken = context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"]
                };
                ValidateRoleViewModel vrvm = new ValidateRoleViewModel
                {
                    Role = Role,
                    SecretKey = SecretKey,
                    Token = tvm
                };
                validateRoleClient.ValidateRole(vrvm);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I declare it above my method:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RolesFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { "role", "abc1234" })]
public IActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

I believe I have declared what I needed to in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<ValidateRoleClient>();
services.AddScoped<RolesFilterAttribute>();
```

However, when I start the app and navigate to the about page, this is what I encounter:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type
>   'App.Link.Filters.RolesFilterAttribute' could not be located. Ensure
>   the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of
>   a public constructor.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type
>   instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, out ConstructorInfo
>   matchingConstructor, out Nullable[] parameterMap)

What else am I missing that I am not declaring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RolesFilterAttribute), …]
```

This says that the filter type you want to create is a `RolesFilterAttribute`. Within the type filter, you are also passing two arguments `"role"` and `"abc1234"`. So when the type filter will trigger the creation of `RolesFilterAttribute` it will look for a constructor that takes those two strings. But there is only a single constructor:

```
public RolesFilterAttribute()
    : base(typeof(RolesFilterAttributeImpl))
{ }
```

So you have two parameters for a parameter-less constructor. That’s why you are getting the error.

Instead, what you want to do is have the `[TypeFilter]` attribute create an actual filter. So you need to pass the `RolesFilterAttributeImpl` type there:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RolesFilterAttributeImpl), Arguments = new object[] { "role", "abc1234" })]
```

At that point, your `RolesFilterAttribute` also becomes redundant, so you can just get rid of that and just define the `RolesFilterAttributeImpl` (which I would rename to just `RolesFilter` since it’s a filter, not an attribute or an attribute implementation).

Furthermore, since you are using `[TypeFilter]`, you do *not* need to register your filter type with your dependency injection container. You only need to have the dependencies of your type registered, so only `ValidateRoleClient` in your case.

So your filter implementation would just look like this:

```
public class RolesFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient;
    private readonly string role;
    private readonly string secretKey;

    public RolesFilter(string role, string secretKey, ValidateRoleClient validateRoleClient)
    {
        this.validateRoleClient = validateRoleClient;
        this.role = role;
        this.secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // …
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    { }
}
```

---

`[TypeFilter]` is btw. just one way to allow specifying filters using attributes. You can also create your own attribute which is then actually just a *filter factory* which is responsible of creating the filter instance at run-time. That’s what `[TypeFilter]` does for you by default.

See also my [related answer on the topic of using dependencies in MVC filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725674/216074).