# Call config setting in action filter attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue? I'm told I can not keep Key/Credentials inside the controller so I tried to retrieve it from the config file and was able to print the value but I'm not able to use it inside the action filter attribute

```
[HttpPost]
[CaptchaValidator(PrivateKey ="123")] //This works
[CaptchaValidator(PrivateKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"])] //Error "Argument must be constant expression"
public ViewResult myForm() 
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably better find a way to inject the configuration reading in constructor of CaptchaValidator
so, it should look like

```
public sealed class CaptchaValidator : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
    private readonly field _secretConfiguration;
    public CaptchaValidator(SecretConfiguration secretConfiguration) 
    {
        _secretConfiguration = secretConfiguration;
    }

    // do OnActionExecuting override and implement reading keys from_secretConfiguration
}
```

Good example is provided here: [How can I use Dependency Injection in a .Net Core ActionFilterAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724974/how-can-i-use-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-actionfilterattribute)

Please, note that approach is used in the most upvoted comment is better than the accepted answer because the accepted answer is representing ServiceLocator (anti)pattern.

Unfortunately, you can't indeed pass Runtime-calculated string in Compile-time setting of attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Since I'm a newbie it would be great if you could explain how to use the above code to match my scenario