# Is it possible to redirect to another action using a custom action filter?

Tags: asp.net-core, custom-attributes, action-filter, custom-action-filter

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET Core actions' custom filter attribute.
I need to redirect to another action in case some data does not exist using a custom method filter.

Here is my attempt:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class| AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IsCompanyExistAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

    public IsCompanyExistAttribute(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        if (context.Companies == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(actionName: "Msg", controllerName: "Account", 
                new { message = "You are not allowed to register, since the company data not exist !!!" });
        }
    }
```

I didn't use `filterContext`. The `RedirectToAction` line appears as an error (with a red underline), of course, since it's a void method, not an action result. As I mentioned I'm not familiar with custom filters.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Simply set the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.result?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property of the [`ActionExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0) instance to your [`RedirectToActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttoactionresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It should look something like the following:

```cs
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
     var controller = filterContext.Controller as ControllerBase; 
     if (context.Companies == null && controller != null)
     {
         filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectToAction(
             actionName: "Msg", 
             controllerName: "Account", 
             new { message = "You are not allowed to register, since the company data not exist !!!" }
         );
     }
     base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
 }
```

Comment: it's great solution, Thank you @Jeremy Caney. I add a vote but my reputation is not enough yet. I get this message (Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded). thank you again. But is it possible to provide me with the usage of a custom attribute that has a constructor? because when I use it like this [IsCompanyExist] I get red line error and the error says (there is no argument given that correspondence to the required formal parameter 'context')

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Caney. I did upvote. If you need to help  with usage I guess the usage for custom filters that has dependancy injection can be solved by using "TypeFilter" but i'm still don't know how to use it properly [TypeFilter(typeof(IsCompanyExistAttribute), Arguments = context )]

Comment: @MedoofromEgypt: Thank you for pointing out the dependency injection issue. While it wasn't the focus of your question, it was something I wanted to ask you about. Because of how attributes work, you can only pass compile-time constants to them via the attribute syntax. There are alternate approaches, however, including the use of `TypeFilter`. Take a look at the following Stack Overflow answer for details on how to inject object instances into your filter: [How can I use Dependency Injection in a .Net Core ActionFilterAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725674/3025856).

Comment: @MedoofromEgypt: Also, as is often the case, I find [@Paul Hiles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246396/paul-hiles) provides [a really useful explanation of dependency injection options](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core) on his blog, with more detail about how to call each option, as well as what their tradeoffs are. I'd definitely give that a read. It should clear up any questions you have on that issue. If not, please post this as a new question, and then point me to it via a comment, and I'll try to answer it when I have time.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy Caney your comments helped me to find how to use custom filters with constructors. and the solution is very simple. I hope to add them to your answer to make it as a complete guide to whom it may concern. First Step as you made just add the constructor. Second Step: I add a service to the StartUp services.AddScoped<IsCompanyExistAttribute>();  Third Step: I use it above the ActionResult like this [ServiceFilter(typeof(IsCompanyExistAttribute))]

Comment: @MedoofromEgypt: Oh, good, I’m glad to hear! Since this is ancillary to the question originally being asked, I recommend that you instead edit your question to include this update. That way, it’s not a complicating factor in what is otherwise a focused question.