Need to pass IServiceProvider as a parameter to constructor of the class
I have a class called as LogAction. In this class I am doing some operation using DI.
And that DI is using Iserviceprovider. So in the constructor, initializing the IServiceProvider.
public class LogAction: ActionFilterAttribute
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
  
  public LogAction(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }

 public override OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    var serviceUtility = _serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType: typeof(ISecurity)) as ISecurity;
 //rest of the code 
 }
}

Till now this is fine. But in my in program.cs, facing issue.
builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new LogActionAttribute(// here I need to pass Iserviceprovider));
});

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Is it c#?  Please confirm.

Yes it is c#. Asp.net core.

Added both to tags.

@user876120 You might not need to instantiate a LogActionAttribute instance here. Instead you might be able to use config.Filters.Add<LogActionAttribute>(); instead.

I trust this question contains the answer you wanna get: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52724974    Using ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices as an option, and there's another high voted answer which might have much more changes.
